# Switching, hiding, toggling layer leaflet similar to accordion using mapbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

How to convert that mapbox legend into an accordion like structure such that when a parent layer name is clicked child layer names are displayed in an indented form below it . I have posted a link below of the current standard structure https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/wms/ however I would like mine to look more like this http://jsfiddle.net/La77L8L9/3/ . The difference is my layer information is coming from the database I am currently adding my layers by creating an element a in my javascript as a clickable link which has the layer name , when the link is clicked the corresponding map is displayed . I have placed a snippet below of how I am currently appending the layer name after retrieving it from database , please not that menu ui holds the name of the base map.

```
function addLayer(map, layer, name, zIndex) {
    var layers = document.getElementById('menu-ui');
    layer.setZIndex(zIndex)
    layer.addTo(map);
    // Create a simple layer switcher that
    // toggles layers on and off.
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = '#';
    if (zIndex == 1) {
        link.className = 'active';
       // link.class = 'accordion-toggle';
    }
    else {
        map.removeLayer(layer);
        this.className = '';
    }
    link.innerHTML = name;
    if (zIndex != 1) {
        link.onclick = function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            if (map.hasLayer(layer)) {
                map.removeLayer(layer);
                this.className = '';
            } else {
                layer.setOpacity(1.0);
                map.addLayer(layer);
                this.className = 'active';
            }
        };
    }
    layers.appendChild(link);
}
```

I am assuming that perhaps there is a way of giving each a element an ID and using .clicked to perform the display from visible to false although this is a bit tricky to do dynamically when using a database to retrieve the layer names. My database has layer ID and if the layer and parentLayerID if that particular layer is a a child of a parent.